# If $ 2^a - 5^b7^c =1$ ....

Tags: linear-algebra

Find all possible values of positive integers a, b, c such that:
$$2^a - 5^b7^c =1$$
While solving this question I surmised that a must be a multiple of 4, since $5^a7^b$ always ends with a $5$. Add one to that and you get a six, which entails that $2^a$ has a 6 at the unit digit's spot, so a must be a multiple of $4$. After that, it's a dead end for me. Anyone have any idea how to proceed?

Comment: Considering mod 5 and mod 7 gives that $a$ is a multiple of $12$. That's all I've got for the moment.

Comment: There are no integer positive solutions... *demonstrationem mirabilem detexi, hanc commentum  exiguitas non caperet...*

Comment: @Raffaele There are *integer* solutions $(1,0,0)$ and $(3,0,1)$, but we look for positiv integers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
$ 2^a\equiv 1\pmod 5$ implies $a\equiv 0\pmod4$,
so write $a=4m$.
Now
$$5^b7^c=2^a-1=(2^{2m}-1)(2^{2m}+1)$$
and the two factors are coprime.
Take it further,
$$5^b7^c=(2^{m}-1)(2^m+1)(2^{2m}+1)$$
and all three factors on the right are pairwise coprime. So at most one of them is divisible by $5$ and at most one is divisible by $7$, meaning that the smallest one must be $=1$, i.e., $m=1$. This gives us
$$5^b7^c=(2^1-1)(2^1+1)(2^2+1)=15$$
which is absurd.

---

Note that we used $b\ge 1$ to conclude $2^a\equiv 1\pmod 5$. If we were to allow $b=0$, we find additional solutions such as $a=1$, $b=c=0$ or $a=3$, $b=0$, $c=1$ and beyond that enter the realm of [Catalan's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture).

Comment: At $5^bz^c = (2^{2m} - 1)(2^{2m}+1)$ one can also note that $2^{2m}-1$ is always a multiple of $3$, but the left hand side isn't.